# How to iterate until longest iterable is exhausted. Using zip_longest to iterate

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to continue to iterate until the longest iterable is exhausted (instead of the shortest as regular zip does). I also need to pass this into a dictionary. However, I'm still missing values. I should have about 1,300 values but only getting about 560. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

my_csv = 'my_csv_file' + '.csv'

some_list = []
another_list = []
my_dictionary = {}

with open(my_csv, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    for row in reader:
        some_list.append(row[0])
        another_list.append(row[1:])

my_dictionary = dict(zip_longest(some_list, another_list, fillvalue=None))

for v in my_dictionary.keys():
    print(v)

count = len(my_dictionary.keys())
print(str(count) + " keys")
```

Comment: Sounds like there are keys with duplicate values, which will collapse to the most recent value (e.g.: `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 1: 'c'}` would collapse to `{1: 'c', 2: 'b'}`.

Comment: or  you're using small list as a key which results in multiple `NaN` as a key but `dict` will only consider one.

Comment: Why do you think that zip_longest will make a difference? You append the exact same number of elements to both lists.

Comment: Please provide a sample input file that showcases your issue. Trim the file down to a dozen or fewer lines so you can post it here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6qh_kNvQ0kOKLiiwDO__cIffNVppLAt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlonsoBonifacio did you figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are keys with duplicate values, which will collapse to the most recent value (e.g.: `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 1: 'c'}` would collapse to `{1: 'c', 2: 'b'}`).

You might want to use `list` as values instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Set-up...

my_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip_longest(some_list, another_list, fillvalue=None)
    my_dictionary[key].append(value)

for v in my_dictionary.keys():
    print(v)

keys = len(my_dictionary)
values = sum(len(value) for value in my_dictionary.itervalues())
print(str(keys) + " keys, " + str(values) +  " values")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to output, but maybe one of these example can help.

Given this csv file content:

```
a,b,c
11,12,13
21,22,23
```

---

**First option** is to place headers in a list then the rest of the data trasposed in another list. Then call `dict()` on the zipped list, no need of `zip_longest` here:

```
with open(my_csv, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader, None) # place headers in a list
    rows = [row for row in zip(*reader)] # this transpose the data

print(rows) #=> [('11', '21'), ('12', '22'), ('13', '23')]

my_dictionary = dict(zip(headers, rows))
print(my_dictionary)
#=> {'a': ('11', '21'), 'b': ('12', '22'), 'c': ('13', '23')}
```

---

**The second option** builds a list of dictionaries:

```
my_dictionaries = []
with open(my_csv, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader, None) # place headers in a list
    for row in reader:
      my_dictionaries.append(dict(zip(headers, row)))

print(my_dictionaries)
#=> [{'a': '11', 'b': '12', 'c': '13'}, {'a': '21', 'b': '22', 'c': '23'}]
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping!

So, my CSV contains URLs. The first column has new URLs. The rest are old URLs. I'd like to look at columns 2 and on ([1:]) and if any of those URLs are found in a group of HTM files, replace it with the new URL (column 1). I ran into an issue when not all URLs were being found which I tracked down to zip(dict()) not iterating completely as there are columns are uneven. I filled in the blanks in my CSV but still couldn't print more than 560 lines. Just spent the day trying the suggestions offered to no avail. Here's a link to a sample CSV.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6qh_kNvQ0kOKLiiwDO__cIffNVppLAt/view?usp=sharing