# zip_longest(*d, fill values='0') doesn't work for all sizes of d

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-itertools

So, I'm using zip_longest to write columns with differents sizes on the same file. I'm using like this:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
d = event_time
export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '0')
with open(filenameOut, 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as Output:
    wr = csv.writer(Output, delimiter=' ')
    wr.writerows(export_data)
Output.close()
```

event_time is a list of N elements, where which element is another list with an unknow size.

The problem is that the zip_longest doesn't work for all  values of N.

If N = 10, it works and on my output file I get something like this on the last lines:
(nine zeros and one different)

```
0 0 0 0 0 99916 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 99918 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 99922 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 99924 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 99932 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 99998 0 0 0 0
```

But, if N=100, I should've get something similar, but with 99 zeros, instead, at the end I got one column with zeros.

Comment: What is the exact N at which the unexpected behavior starts?

Comment: I can't reproduce this when I try building my own data sets. Are you sure your big set of data contains what you think it does? How are you building it? Can you give an example dataset that produces the bad output you've described?

Comment: Yes, the problem really was with my DataSet. I couldn't fid a way to put it here, because it cames from a huge pre processing. The problem is the same as this one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719942/how-to-iterate-until-longest-iterable-is-exhausted-using-zip-longest-to-iterate

I didn't thought it was here, because my dataSet wasn't supposed to have the same value, specially not in the same line.